# How to apply transparency to a background that changes color smoothly

Tags: javascript, background, transparency, mousemove

I want to make a div with transparent background smoothly changing color, the problem is that I need to have some content at the div which will not be transparent.

I found this for changing the color

```
<head>
<script 
   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
setInterval ( "spectrum()", 1000 );
   }); 

function spectrum(){
var hue = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + 
   (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + 
   (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';
$('body').css( { backgroundColor: hue });

}

</script>
</head>
</body>
</html>
```

But I have no clue how to add the transparency into it.

The other thing I would like is to change the color by moving the with the cursor. I think it should be possible to combine it with the jQuery `.mousemove()` function.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format for semi-transparent colour is `rgba( R, G, B, A)`, where `R`, `G`, `B` are what you already have, and `A` is a number between 0 (fully transparent) and 1 (fully opaque). It's up to you to determine what the exact number you need is.

Comment: thanks it works well, and do you know how to change the color with use of coordinates of the mouse I saw it once and I think that at least two of the numbers from the rgb should be possible to change to the X and Y of the position of the cursor at window.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS for transition:

```
body{
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1s linear;
}
```

Live code:
http://jsbin.com/oqesub/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Change `rgb` to `rgba`.

```
rgba(red,green,blue,opacity)
```