# Optimizing JQuery color changes script

Tags: jquery, css, optimization, jquery-animate

can this code below be further optimized?  I feel that it's using too much resources as it is written now (my JS testing knowledge is close to nothing...).
I welcome tips and rewrites.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$(document).ready(function() {setInterval(function () {spectrum()},5000); });

 function spectrum(){
    var hue = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';
    $('.front-panel-heading').animate( { backgroundColor: hue },7000);
    $('#content h2 > span').animate( {color:hue}, 7000);
    $('#colophon > div > span').animate( {color:hue}, 7000);
 };
});
```

Notes:
the script is live on my personal website (apleasantview.com)
I've been using this for a while and today I cleaned it up a little as well as adding 'transition' in my css as suggested in the third answer here:
[How to apply transparency to a background that changes color smoothly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464873/how-to-apply-transparency-to-a-background-that-changes-color-smoothly)

Thx in advance -Cris.

//code update 1 following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/24079418/2947983

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

setInterval(function () {spectrum()},5000);

function spectrum(){
    var hue = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';

    $('div#front-panel-bkgr').animate( {backgroundColor:hue}, 7000);
    $('span#clr-swtch').animate( {color:hue}, 7000);

 };

});
```

//code update 2 following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/24121309/2947983

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    setInterval(function () {
        spectrum()
    }, 7000);

    var frontPanel = $('div#front-panel-bkgr'),
        clrSwitch = $('span#clr-swtch'),
        timer = 7000;
        spectrum();

    function spectrum() {
        var hue = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';
        frontPanel.animate({backgroundColor: hue}, timer);
        clrSwitch.animate({color: hue}, timer);
    };
});
```

Comment: the color must be always the same for both elements or it can be different for each one?

Comment: sorry @LGVentura I've only seen your comment now. colors must always be the same for both elements, yes. I've meanwhile updated the code in my question, should you have anything to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Reduce the number of DOM lookups

You are looking up the same dom elements every time you run this code. You can store the jQuery objects in a variable outside of the function to improve cpu-sage.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    setInterval(function () {
        spectrum()
    }, 5000);

    var frontPanel = $('div#front-panel-bkgr'),
        clrSwitch = $('span#clr-swtch');

    function spectrum() {
        var hue = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';
        frontPanel.animate({backgroundColor: hue}, 7000);
        clrSwitch.animate({color: hue}, 7000);
    };
});
```

### Timing

Your animations are taking two seconds longer than then `setInterval` is calling the function. You might be OK for the first loop or two, but eventually you will have the elements trying to change to two or three colours at the same time. Remove the `setInterval` and add the function as the callback to one of the animate functions. Also, if you want both animations to take the same amount of time to run, replace the `7000` with a variable. This will allow you to change the value during development in one place only and have both rules run at the same time:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    var frontPanel = $('div#front-panel-bkgr'),
        clrSwitch = $('span#clr-swtch'),
        timer = 7000;
    spectrum();
    function spectrum() {
        var hue = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';
        frontPanel.animate({backgroundColor: hue}, timer);
        clrSwitch.animate({color: hue}, timer, spectrum());
    };
});
```

**[edit]**

Because the callback is self-referencing there is going to be an infinite loop going on. I think the browser (or perhaps jQuery?) has worked that out and is throwing the range error. To get around this, wrap the callback in an anonymous function:

```
        clrSwitch.animate({color: hue}, timer, function() {spectrum();});
```

Comment: Adding the spectrum() function as callback (cf. Timing) gave me a RangeError in the console. I did pick up on adding timer as a variable to your first example. Keeping setInterval also leaves the color looping like intended. Updating question with the code. Should you have any remarks or other bits of info, please do shoot -cheers

Comment: The callback is self-referencing so the browser is throwing an exception. Wrap the callback in an anonymous function to get around this. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

1) if there is only one span in `#content h2` or in `#colophon > div` than add id to them

2) You are using double `$(document).ready()`, use only first, and move function spectrum away from `$(document).ready`

3) `.front-panel-heading` - can't it be replaced with id?

Comment: from your reply I've updated my JS code.  I've noticed that my laptop fan didn't go crazy when I leave the site open if this can be taken as indication of improvement.  however could you clarify me the following:  in point 1 and 3, are you suggesting I should try to target ID's instead of classes for better perfomance as a general rule?  point 2: I'm not exactly sure what you meant. Could you verify if the updated code above in the question?

Comment: @cristovaov Yes, if possible, use ID instead of class for single element. Updated code removed double `$(document).ready`. And finally - your laptop fan is not indicator of website js usage. I don't think that you have so many elements and loops inside your webpage, that it would take lots of CPU/GPU.

Comment: thanks for all your input, it set me on a good track. as for the fan, call me supersitious: chrome did seem to over-run prior that, making my fan go harder...